# What is the default learning rate, optimizer and activation function in Tensorflow's estimator API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

Suppose we have `LinearRegressor` and `DNNLinearRegressor` models available in the Tensorflow estimator API.

However, the documentation does not clearly mention what the default optimizers, learning rate and activation functions are used by this API.

Please, let me know if you know the answer to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- If you look at **[LinearRegressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearRegressor)** for  you will see the default optimizer is **[FTRL](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/FtrlOptimizer)** with yet undefined learning rate. Mean squared error is used as a loss function.
- Moreover, **[DNNRegressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNRegressor)** uses **[Adagrad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdagradOptimizer)** optimizer with undefined learning rate and **[ReLU](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu)** activations.

As you can see, everything is there. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I can see where this information is. However, I was still not able to find where does it say that the loss function used is mean squared error. I am also trying to find the loss function used for linear classifier and hence the follow up question

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py#L235) the default is the squared one.